# You are not logged in. Please log in and try again

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using phonegap facebook connect plugin (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) for Facebook Authentication in app. It was working till today morning. Now suddenly it stops working and gives error as below for different devices iOS & Android:

For Android:

> You are not logged in. You are not logged in. Please log in and try again.

For iOS:

> Given URL is not allowed by the application configuration: One or more of the given URL is not allowed by the App’s settings. To use this URL you must add a valid native platform in your App’s settings

I'm using following code in `config.xml`:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">    
     <param name="APP_ID" value="99885XXXXXXXXX" />
     <param name="APP_NAME" value="Test App" />
</gap:plugin>
```

facebook call:

```
function fbLogin() {
        facebookConnectPlugin.login(
        ["public_profile", "email"],
        function (response) {
            var OAuthToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            var OAuthAccessToken = response.authResponse.userID;
            if (response.authResponse) {
                facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me', null,
                    function (me_response) {
                        alert("Success: " + me_response);
                        facebookConnectPlugin.logout(function (response) {}, function (response) {});                            
                    });
            }                
        },
        function (response) {                
            alert("Error: " + me_response);
        }
    );
}
```

Don't know what is the issue here.

Comment: If it's suddenly happening for both iOS and Android, and it was working before, it sounds like something changed in the developer settings for your Facebook app. I'd check your page at developers.facebook.com to make sure everything is correct

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I had the exact same problem which popped up last few days or so. I fixed it by generating the respective platforms in the app's settings. Note that I only had the general settings before and it worked, but something probably been changed recently.

1. Go to he settings section of your app in Facebook (Facebook developers > My Apps then Settings)
2. Under the Basics make sure you have the respective platform. If you do and it is still not working, then remove and recreate it. Otherwise, click on [+ Add Platform] and follow the instructions. For example, for Android you need to provide:
   a) Your package id
   b) Your launcher activity full name
   c) Key hash - which you need to generate as per instructions using keytool and openssl

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's now working. but there is one issue. I'd used my old facebook app (which is a card game app & app v2.0) with this app I'm able to get "public_profile" data but with newly created app (which is a fashion app & app v2.4) but not able to get all profile data with same code posted in question. Is there anything new in v2.4 or need to submit app for allow permission?

Comment: Hard to answer without the details, but I doubt you need a full submission. If I understood you correctly, you still need to supply your permissions in your graph api call, but in your code above the second parameter is null. Instead, it should look something like this:  
`facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me', ['public_profile', 'user_birthday'], function(me_response){ ...`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check your solution for the above comment but the trick worked for me is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938903/facebook-login-responce-not-get-users-details-except-id-and-name?noredirect=1#comment51794272_31938903 here.

Comment: The non-web api endpoints seem to only allow basic info on initial auth. You'll have to get detailed data only after the user has given the initial basic authorization. Unfortunately doesn't appear to be a way around it.

Comment: I did all things mentioned in answer, but still getting the 'not logged in' error...

Comment: It didn't work for me, so I created another app, configured the platforms and it worked

Comment: Worked for me. In my case I missed to add the platform for my app. Just added the package name e full launcher activity. The key hash wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this by using replace the redirect URL:
 `http://localhost/callback`

For more info visit:
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/

Comment: Note that Facebook no longer allows "http" for Valid OAuth Redirect URIs

Answer (score 2):

well, in my case i have not made the app public .
go to app review part of your app and turn **"Make your app public?"** to yes .
try it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

All my research efforts lead me to this thread.
What did the trick in my case was adding this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

to the Valid OAuth redirect URIs in the facebook login settings.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, Please cross check your domain name on Facebook APP. My domain name was changes so It was not working, once I have make it correct Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect url in app and Facebook app should be equal