# Facebook login responce : Not Get Users details except (Id and name)

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, phonegap-plugins

Facebook login responce not getting user's all Details like email, firstname, lastname. Its works fine in Facebook Graph API v2.0 but not in v2.4. I am using this plugin for PhoneGap application. this repository from https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect

```
if (response.authResponse) {
      facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me', null,
           function (me_response) {
               var username = me_response.email;
               var firstname = me_response.first_name;
               var lastname = me_response.last_name;
               var ExternalIdentifier = me_response.id;
               var Email = me_response.email;                           
               var ProviderSystemName = "ExternalAuth.Facebook";
               ExternalResponseInsert(apiSecretKey, storeId, languageId, username, firstname, lastname, Email, ExternalIdentifier, OAuthToken, OAuthAccessToken, ProviderSystemName);
                    facebookConnectPlugin.logout(function (response) {}, function (response) {});                            
               });
            }
```

Comment: you need to update the api , you probably using the old api with newer version application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook only returning name and id of user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692355/facebook-only-returning-name-and-id-of-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reference from [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692355/facebook-only-returning-name-and-id-of-user/31692908#31692908)

Looks like you're using v2.4 of the Graph API. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> **Declarative Fields**
>   To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you **explicitly request the field(s) you need** for your GET requests. For example, `GET /me` no longer includes likes and comments by default, but `GET /me?fields=id,name,username,emails,first_name,last_name` will return the data. For more details see the docs on how to request specific fields.