# cordova-plugin-facebook4 ionic facebookConnectPlugin is not defined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working on ionic project and i have installed this plugin cordova-plugin-facebook4
but when  i'm trying to use it in controller

```
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
        console.log ("dzdqsdqs");

    $scope.login=function() {
      console.log ("dzdqsdqs");
            facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email'], function(response) {
                alert('Logged in');
                alert(JSON.stringify(response.authResponse));
            }, function(error){
                alert(error);
            })
        }
})
```

I got this error : 
ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined

Comment: Are you trying this on browser? Because this isn't going to work on browser you have to install it on device or emulator

Comment: yes i 'm trying on browser
this code is  correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @bakrim in the comments, you need to run this code on a device or emulator.

To run on an iOS emulator:

```
ionic platform add ios
ionic build ios
ionic emulate ios
```

To run on an Android simulator:

```
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
ionic emulate android
```

For more information on running on real devices: http://junerockwell.com/how-to-run-ionic-on-real-devices/

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879804/you-are-not-logged-in-please-log-in-and-try-again

Comment: I turned on App view to public But still not working

Comment: if i generate o hashes key from my computer can i do test on my real mobile